# Detect the pitch of a live audio input in the browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

How can you detect the pitch of a live audio input in the browser?

The below code will get you 1,024 frequency values. However I don't know how to go from this to actual pitches (e.g. A#).

```
const audioContext = new window.AudioContext();
const analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();

navigator.getUserMedia(
  { audio: true },
  stream => {
    audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream).connect(analyser);

    const dataArray = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);

    analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(dataArray);

    // Log the contents of the analyzer ever 500ms. 
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log(dataArray.length);
    }, 500);
  },
  err => console.log(err)
);
```

Answer (score 4):

What you are currently accessing is the Time Domain Data, and can not be used to retrieve a note (which seems to be what you want).

What you'd want is the Frequency Domain, using [AnalyserNode.get[XXX]FrequencyData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/getByteFrequencyData), from which you could get which frequencies are louder or more quiet.

However, since most sound is made of harmonies, you can't retrieve what *note* was played from a microphone, add to this that we only have access to limited resolution, and not only will you be unable to retrieve a note from a microphone, but not even from a virtual oscillator either.

Below example has been made from [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50376861/how-to-get-frequency-value-in-javascript) and [examples from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/getByteFrequencyData#Example);

```js
const canvasCtx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const WIDTH = canvas.width = 500;
const HEIGHT = canvas.height = 150;

const audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext);
const analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();

const nyquist = audioCtx.sampleRate / 2;

// highest precision
analyser.fftSize = 32768;

const bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
const dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);
const osc = audioCtx.createOscillator();
osc.frequency.value = 400;
osc.connect(analyser);
osc.connect(audioCtx.destination);

range.oninput = e => {
  osc.frequency.value = range.value;
};

if(!audioCtx.state || audioCtx.state === 'running') {
  begin();
}
else {
  log.textContent = 'click anywhere to begin';
  onclick = e => {
    onclick = null;
    begin()
  }
}

function begin() {
  osc.start(0);
  draw();
}

function draw() {
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);

  // get the Frequency Domain
  analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);

  canvasCtx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
  canvasCtx.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

  const barWidth = (WIDTH / bufferLength) * 2.5;
  let max_val = -Infinity;
  let max_index = -1;
  let x = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {
    let barHeight = dataArray[i];
    if(barHeight > max_val) {
      max_val = barHeight;
      max_index = i;
    }

    canvasCtx.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + (barHeight+100) + ',50,50)';
    canvasCtx.fillRect(x,HEIGHT-barHeight/2,barWidth,barHeight/2);
    x += barWidth;
  }
  log.textContent = `loudest freq: ${max_index * (nyquist / bufferLength)}
real value: ${range.value}`;
}
```

```css
#log{display: inline-block; margin:0 12px}
#canvas{display: block;}
```

```html
<input id="range" type="range" min="0" max="1000" value="400"><pre id="log"></pre>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```